# Enabling GPIO on Linux from sysfs

Tags: linux, assembly, gpio, sysfs

I have an ITX industrial motherboard based on **Intel HM77** which has on board GPIO pins.

I wish to enable GPIO by `echo pinNumber > /sys/class/gpio/export` as I normally do on Raspberry Pi. However, I can't figure out the value of `pinNumber`

**Here's a table of available GPIO pins**

[image]

**Enable GPIO68**

```
mov edx, 500h+40h

in eax, edx

mov ebx, 00000010h ; bit4, GPIO_USE_SEL3[68]

or eax, ebx ; Set bit4 of GPIO_USE_SEL3

out edx, eax
```

I tried using `echo 68 > /sys/class/gpio/export` **which outputs:** `write error: no such device`

GPIO can be used from sysfs as `gpiochip180` is found in `/sys/class/gpio/gpiochip180`

How can I enable a GPIO pin in Linux without using assembly?

Comment: Do you have `/sys/kernel/debug/gpio`? What does it say? Anything in syslog?

Comment: @Jester Yes I have it. Contains one line: `GPIOs 180-255, platform/gpio_ich:`

Comment: Looks like your gpio numbers are based at 180 then, so try `180+68=248`. Also note that `40h` is `64` not `68`.

Comment: @Jester Thanks, 248 works! If you want add it as an answer so that I can accept it.